# Best practice to query an Azure database that is being updated repeatedly

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure database (using SQL Database), and also a separate device that measures floats (not relevant to the question).

As and when the data is being updated, say once every 5 minutes, I wish to update the database so that a new row is being formed with this data. I then intend to connect to PowerBI using the Azure database to form graphs etc.

As mentioned in the title, what would be the best practice? I have done my due diligence and it seems that the best way would just be to update the Azure database. Or should I consider updating a CSV file, then connect the CSV file to the Azure database and update it from there?

Reason why I'm considering to go the CSV file route is because I see that Excel has in-built refresh function, but I couldn't find anything from the Azure side.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/refresh-an-external-data-connection-in-excel-1524175f-777a-48fc-8fc7-c8514b984440

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Excel, you can see this Azure official document: [Connect Excel to a single database in Azure SQL database and create a report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel).

Connect Excel to a single database in Azure SQL Database and import data and create tables and charts based on values in the database. In this tutorial you will set up the connection between Excel and a database table, save the file that stores data and the connection information for Excel, and then create a pivot chart from the database values.

[image]

Then, you can use the "Refresh Data" and try the tutorial you have found.

Hope this helps.